# Retrieve documents from DocuSign using a signer's email address

Tags: docusignapi

I want to be able to query the DocuSign REST API for a list of envelopes that are associated with a signer's email address, which I will pass in with my API query.

This would be the same functionality as going to DocuSign.net, then clicking on Manage, and then entering a signer's email address in the search bar ( of course customizing the search parameters ), and being presented all documents associated with that email address.

The only material I've found so far in the API guide is to get a list of envelopes, then a list of documents, and then a list of details per document...that's a lot of looping to perform what appears to be a simple search done through the GUI.

Thanks for any assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a REST API call called search_folders, which can be used to return information about envelopes in a specific state, date range, and includes details on the recipients. You would still need to post-process the results for the recipients in question, but it prevents multiple API calls (IMO).

### Online documentation:

[Link Here](https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/RESTAPIGuide.htm#REST%20API%20References/Get%20List%20of%20Envelopes%20in%20Folders.htm?Highlight=search_folders)

Get List of Envelopes in Folders
This returns a list of envelopes that match the criteria specified in the query.

**URL:** `/accounts/{accountId}/search_folders/{search_folder}`

**Optional query additions:** `start_position={integer}, count={integer}, from_date={date/time}, to_date={date/time}, order_by={string}, order={string}, include_recipients={true/false}, all`

Comment: Luis,Thanks for your response. Following my original post, I realized that I not only need the envelopeId but I also need the templateId/powerformId .. so looking at the docs it appears that I can query for a templateId based on envelopeId, but not query for powerform Id. So, your answer does solve the original query I had, but not the whole problem. I'll mark your answer as correct though.

Comment: Appears that the API isn't designed to allow for a direct query for all envelopes based on a user's email address ( as it *is* in the docusign.net web interface search, under "Manage" tab ). And so, if I want all envelopes for a given user and the 'type' of document, I'd have to use Connect to send me XML on the doc, capture the user email and envelopeId, then query the API for the templateId used to create the given envelopeId. Bass Ackwards. So, that's my solution, since internally I have different doc types...the templateIds allow me to differentiate the doc types. Any better solutions?